# нужно ли обособление при сравнительном обороте

Tags: запятые, как

Хочется_ как в 19 веке_ уехать на воды, лечить нервы.

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли запятые для обособления сравнительного оборота (если он есть)?

Благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Хочется, **как в 19 веке**, уЕхать на воды, лечИть нервы.*

**Есть ли здесь сравнение?** Да, несомненно, это именно сравнение. А  сравниваем-то что? А вот предмет сравнения как бы  опущен: уехать сейчас, как в 19 веке.
Позиция для обособления оборота самая подходящая: между глаголом-связкой и основным глаголом.  Так что без обособления, скорее всего, не обойтись.

**Наверное, вам ссылки на правила нужны?** Ну вот у Розенталя есть похожий пример:  В тот день Мария, как буря, влетела в хату; http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147, пункт 3.

Здесь тоже обособленный сравнительный оборот в значении обстоятельства, хотя обособление скорее факультативное. Тогда вот такие есть примеры: В лицо пахнуло, точно из погреба, сырым холодом. Проглянет день, как будто поневоле, и скроется за край далёких гор. Друзья, как во сне, вышли на улицу.

**Может быть, по поводу интонации сомневаетесь?** Это верно, интонацию надо проверить. Логическим ударением выделены **однородные сказуемые**, а как же тогда еще и оборот обособлять? А его вставочной интонацией и не выделяют, только обозначают обычным ударением, фразового (тонического)  ударения у оборота нет. В данном случае главное – это обозначить перечислительную интонацию для сказуемых.

**Я очень надеюсь, что вам понятно мое объяснение.**

А у меня к вам такой вопрос: почему вы не принимаете ответы у наших участников?  Неужели ни один из них не решил ваши проблемы?

Comment: Спасибо большое!  
Да, многие ответы, в том числе Ваши, очень помогли.
Просто не до конца поняла правила сайта. Исправлюсь.

Comment: Вот и прекрасно, что мы поняли друг друга. У вас интересные вопросы, с удовольствием ответим на них.